# black screen when trying to loopback desktop with v4l2loopback in proxmox guest VM

Tags: fedora, v4l2loopback

### Background

i'm currently trying to setup an Android Emulator for WhatsApp bridging with my Matrix-Server. I followed the instructions here up to the point where i have to setup a webcam for the QR-Scanning: https://docs.mau.fi/bridges/go/whatsapp/android-vm-setup.html

### Problem

I'm trying to loopback my Desktop screen with the following command

```
 ffmpeg -s 1024x600  -f x11grab -i :1+10,20 -vf format=pix_fmts=yuv420p -f v4l2 /dev/video0
```

Afterwards i'm checking the video signal with

```
mplayer tv:// -tv driver=v4l2:device=/dev/video0
```

But all i can see is a black window. Somehow this does not seem to work.

### Prerequisites

I have installed the kernel module using

```
sudo dnf install v4l2loopback
```

and loaded the module with

```
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback
```

The VM guest is a fedora 33, which runs in a proxmox hypervisor v6.4-13.

is that in general possible to do in a VM guest? Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer [on the ArchLinux Forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=222780). It seems that the X11 plugin for `ffmpeg` does not work with Wayland.